# Remove all items from ArrayList after a specific item

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an array list

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("Apple"); 
  list.add("Ball");  
  list.add("Cat");  
  list.add("dog");  
  list.add("Egg");
```

And I want to remove all items after "Cat".

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get a `subList(...)` of the remaining elements, and `clear()` it:

```
int index = list.indexOf("Cat");
if (index > -1) {
    list.subList(index + 1, list.size()).clear();
}
```

I see other answer attempts are trying to use `remove` and `removeAll` methods.
That's not efficient,
because the `remove(Object)` and `removeAll(Collection)` methods try match elements in the list, which requires scanning the entire list.
Worse, if elements may appear multiple times,
then those techniques may incorrectly remove elements before the target too.
Using `subList` and `clear` is correct, efficient and simple.

Comment: Thanks, man it works :)

Comment: Thanks @Christopher!

Comment: @davidxxx no it doesn't. See the description of Throws in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) (You could also give it a try.)